# How can I enable a newer (installed) kernel in Debian / EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, kernel

I have an `m1.large` paravirtual EC2 instance running Debian Wheezy. It appears that I have two kernel packages installed: one 2.6 kernel and one 3.2 kernel. The 2.6 kernel is the one that is enabled and running.

```
$ uname -a
Linux nodename 2.6.32-312-ec2 #24-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 18:30:50 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'd like to switch to the newer kernel and I'm not sure how to do that. If this were bare hardware, I'd make sure that `grub` knew about the new kernel, make it the default, and (if necessary) install the bootloader onto the boot sector of the primary disk.

Since this is EC2, I'm not sure what the procedure should be.

The file `/boot/grub/menu.lst` exists, and contains:

```
default 0
timeout 3
title EC2
   root (hd0)
   kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 4
   initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64
```

That on-disk kernel does exist, but isn't the currently-running one. Also, the `grub2` package isn't installed and `/boot/grub/menu.lst` hasn't been updated since 2011. So, I expect it's not relevant, here.

What's the process for enabling a new kernel on Debian/EC2? What about being able to fall-back to a known-working kernel if the new one doesn't work?

Comment: Use an HVM instance so you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: There really is no reason to still be using PV. Newer instance types do not even support any more (eg m4.X, released 3 years ago).

Comment: Also, Wheezy is EOL in 4 months.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you explain why this is a PV problem and wouldn't happen to an HVM instance?

Comment: Same problem here. Is it possible to change from PV to HVM keeping same IP and keys?

Comment: @LucasBr You should probably ask a separate question, but I think the answer is "no, you cannot change a VM's instance type". So, you'll probably need to create a completely new instance, which means a new IP address. If you are using an elastic IP, you can switch it to the new instance. You can certainly re-use the keys if you are using Amazon's KSM.